# SignalR: can't connect to local or any other ip address

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, server, signalr, signalr-hub

I am trying to make SignalR server and client architecture in which i am able to connect to "http://localhost:8080" or http://127.0.0.1:8080/ but i am not able to connect my local ip address like "192. x.x.x" so what could be reason?
please help me i am also placing my code overhere...

```
 public partial class WinFormsServer : Form
        {
            private IDisposable SignalR { get; set; }
            const string ServerURI = "http://localhost:8080";

     private void ButtonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                WriteToConsole("Starting server...");
                ButtonStart.Enabled = false;
                Task.Run(() => StartServer());
            }
     private void StartServer()
            {
                try
                {
                    SignalR = WebApp.Start(ServerURI);
                }
                catch (TargetInvocationException)
                {
                    WriteToConsole("Server failed to start. A server is already running on " + ServerURI);
                    //Re-enable button to let user try to start server again
                    this.Invoke((Action)(() => ButtonStart.Enabled = true));
                    return;
                }
                this.Invoke((Action)(() => ButtonStop.Enabled = true));
                WriteToConsole("Server started at " + ServerURI);
            }
     class Startup
        {
            public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
            {
                app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
                app.MapSignalR();
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your `local IP address` you could use this function:

```
public static string GetLocalIPAddress()
        {
            var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
            {
                if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                {
                    return ip.ToString();
                }
            }
            throw new Exception("Local IP Address Not Found!");
        }
```

If you want to use FQDN - Fully Qualified Domain Name, then you could use this function:

```
public static string GetLocalFQDN()
        {
            var props = IPGlobalProperties .GetIPGlobalProperties();
            return props.HostName + (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(props.DomainName) ? "" : "." + props.DomainName);
        }
```

After that you could use:

```
SignalR = WebApp.Start("http://" + GetLocalFQDN() + ":8080");
```

or

```
SignalR = WebApp.Start("http://" + GetLocalIPAddress() + ":8080");
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: sorry but for me i am facing the same problem

Comment: i got the sample overhere  https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Using-SignalR-in-WinForms-f1ec847b

Comment: I tried again and it worked for me:
replace const string ServerURI with string ServerURI =String.Concat("http://",GetLocalFQDN(),":8080");

Comment: Check my comment for GetLocalFQDN(), and to use this you need to also use using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

Comment: thanx for your help...but still facing the same problem... i am getting an exception of  'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' ....i got this sample on https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Using-SignalR-in-WinForms-f1ec847b..

Comment: please look at this problem ..if you have working code can u send me ? or any link where i can find solution to this ....actually this is winform an if i want to make a .exe file and run on any computer then server must start and can connect to any client on another pc... i am new to this ...please help me that will be great help

Comment: Yes i have the working version. I will post as another comment the exact changes i made. Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

I tried different solutions but could not find correct one.

**Finally** I found the issue that was only related to the **permission**.
Run your SignalR server application **as administrator**. It will start running on the local IP like **192.168.X.X:9090** and then your client application can connect this server from any other PC using this IP address.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var url = $"http://{GetLocalIPAddress()}:8080";
        using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url))
        {                
            Console.WriteLine($"Server running at {{{url}}}");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public static string GetLocalIPAddress()
    {
        var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
        {
            if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                return ip.ToString();
            }
        }
        throw new Exception("Local IP Address Not Found!");
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you kidding me! I have literally been searching months for this solution... I ended up hosting through IIS but revisited this issue as I know there had to be a simple solution and sure enough here it was.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using [this source](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Using-SignalR-in-WinForms-f1ec847b) i used the same too.
-For FQDN, first create the function below.

```
public static string GetLocalFQDN()
                {
                    var props = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
                    return props.HostName + (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(props.DomainName) ? "" : "." + props.DomainName);
                }
```

Then modify the `const string ServerURI` to:

```
string ServerURI =String.Concat("http://",GetLocalFQDN(),":8080");
```

-For LocalIPAdress, first create the function below which will the your local address:

```
public static string GetLocalIPAddress()
        {
            var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
            {
                if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                {
                    return ip.ToString();
                }
            }
            throw new Exception("Local IP Address Not Found!");
        }
```

and change the `string ServerURI =String.Concat("http://",GetLocalFQDN(),":8080");` to:

```
string ServerURI =String.Concat("http://",GetLocalIPAddress(),":8080");
```

Hope this helps you.

**Note:** The changes should be done in the `WinFormsServer:Form` class on the `WinFormsServer` project.

Comment: sorry brother...this is not working for me because I am getting value of ServerURI= "http://192.*.*.*:8080"  which is not woking  but for "http://127.0.0.1:8080" it is working..it might be possible that issues will be with ipaddress ...thank u so much bro for ur help... nowi am looking for other solutions ...if u have working code can you give that sample..

Comment: actually i was debugging GetLocalIPAddress() method in which i got an exception of system.net.sockets.socketException .... i think it could be the reason of my probelm..let me check hope it will get reolved

Comment: I have the sample you have with the samples i sent. Wish you the best :)

Comment: yeah ...it's working just i have to run visual studio in Administrator mode...it took so much time...thanx @etr

Comment: it's working on my pc.... server and client are connecting on same pc...but if i run the server on any other pc and client on another pc connected via lan....then it's not working (i have put server ip address in client url) actually i am new to this so i have to run server on another machine and client on another machine ...how can i do this?